# Como usar wp_enqueue_style?

Tags: wordpress

Como faço para que a página contato.php utilize o arquivo contato.css utilizando a função wp_enqueue_style no Wordpress?

```
function terradecultivo_scripts() { 
if (contato.php) {  
    wp_enqueue_style('terra-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/contato.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'terra-style' );
```

Este código coloquei no function.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou *is_page_template*? Algo como:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'contato.php' ) ) {
     wp_enqueue_style('terra-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/contato.css' );
}
```

Referência http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template